# Does shell() in R remember the previous command?

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a batch file via R and I'm trying to use `shell()` to do so. This is written over two separate instances of `shell()`, one to set the directory and one to run the file:

```
shell("cd <file location>")
shell("activate.bat")
```

While troubleshooting I ran `shell("dir")` and it returns the current working directory of the R and *not* the directory set via `shell()`.

Is `shell()` unable to retain memory between different instances of it being used, and if so is it possible to run two terminal commands in R when one relies on the other being run first?

Comment: No, each call to `shell` starts with a new shell. It starts with R's current working directory, though, so you can first (in R) `setwd("location")` (abs or rel path) and then `shell("activate.bat")`.

Comment: @r2evans I've attempted this but it still seems to be failing. I've changed the code to `setwd(<file location>)`  `shell('cd')` and it's returning a different location.

Comment: You are mis-using `cd`. The default action of `cd` given no arguments is to change to the `$HOME` directory (if set). If you want to just return what the present working directory is (according to `shell`), try `shell("pwd")`.

Comment: If you want one command which temporarily sets the path and then runs `activate.bat` then `shell("cd path & activate.bat")` where `path` is replaced by the path to cd to.  For example, `shell("cd %userprofile%/Downloads & dir")`

Comment: @r2evans That gives me an error stating `'pwd' is not recognized as an internal or external command...`, but I've resolved the issue thanks to your first comment - the different location was returned due to me running these lines in a notebook chunk in different runs, causing the wd to reset between them. Running them in one go has successfully changed the directory returned with `shell('cd')` to the intended one and ran the batch file.

Comment: Okay, I incorrectly assumed you were working with POSIX-compatible tools around (such as provided by Rtools, git-for-windows, or WSL). @G.Grothendieck's `cd path & activate.bat` may be the best way for you to go. (Note that the use of `setwd()` lasts throughout the chunk, so if you need different locations, you'll need to `setwd(..)` again.)